# plpythonu.control Missing on Postgres 9.4.0

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-postgresql

I'm running Postgres 9.4.0 on my Mac.

I keep getting this error when running my migrations:

PG::UndefinedFile: ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/share/postgresql/extension/plpythonu.control": No such file or directory

I checked and (of course) that file is missing from that directory.

I tried doing:

```
$ psql 
=# \c abc_dev;
=# CREATE EXTENSION plpythonu;
=# ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/share/postgresql/extension/plpythonu.control": No such file or directory
```

How can I get the plpythonu.control file into the extension section on my Mac so I can add it to the abc_dev database? Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Note for guy like me. Related, but not directly, to the OP. Look at the error you are getting carefully. Mine was similar the OQ error except `plpythonu.control` was actually `plpython3u.control`; therefore, look in directory `/[some install path here]/extension' for `plpython3u.control` Then run `CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u`. Different version of `py` (I think).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: The standard brew does not include plpython. You can get it to work by using:
`brew reinstall postgresql --build-from-source --with-python`

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. You can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question

Comment: Well, it might not be the most definitive answer, but it certainly does help along the way. Anyhow, this might be a bit more definitive answer: 
`brew reinstall postgresql --build-from-source --with-python`


Just found out about it, sorry :)

Comment: If you think you found a better answer edit your actual answer to reflect it, remember the objective of this site is to help others and we try to keep it clean and sound

Comment: That did it, thank you @ervazu. Thanks for your help as well, jean.